# What will be the best approach implementing infinite/repeating scrolling world in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, sprite-kit

While moving the character it must stay inside a rectangle centred on the screen and all other game objects must scroll.

But as you get to the edge of the world it must repeat.
The characters can move in any direction.

Answer (score 3):

You have to divide the world in 3 sections. Section 1 and 3 must be identical. If you reach the end of the world (Section 3) you can switch back to section 1.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FX-tFks5pg

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The bad thing with this is I have to keep game objects in section 3 synchronized with objects in section 1. So that when an object in section 1 changes its position or something because of collision, the object's replica in section 3 must be updated

Comment: Ok. I solved it. that way for my game: I've created a small datastructure which represents the state of a game element.  Then I divided my game scene into columns which contains the states and a key to link them to the game elements. Before switching the screen I'm looping through the newly visible columns and update the game elements.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please? When you update the state? How often? Does each column contains the states of elements inside it? How many elements were you able to handle? Don't you have frame rate issues?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        _background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
        _background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        _background.name = @"background";
        _background.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        [self addChild:_background];
}
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if (_lastUpdateTime) {
        _deltaTime = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
    } else {
        _deltaTime = 0;
    }
    _lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
    if (_deltaTime > 1) {
        _deltaTime = 1.0 / 60.0;
    }
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"background" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)     {
        node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x - backgroundMoveSpeed * _deltaTime, node.position.y);
        if (node.position.x < - (node.frame.size.width + 100)) {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
    }];
    if (_background.position.x < -bound) { 
        //bound = 500
        SKSpriteNode *temp = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
        temp.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        temp.name = @"background";
        temp.position = CGPointMake(_background.position.x + _background.frame.size.width, 0);
        [self addChild:temp];
        _background = temp;
    }
```

the background image's size is 2048x640, so you should change the bound according to your background image's size.